# Shell prompt that is based on location in filesystem

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, command-prompt

I have to work within three main directories under the root filesystem - home/username, project, and scratch. I want my shell prompt to display which of these top level directories i am in.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
top_level_dir ()
{
    if [[ "${PWD}" == *home* ]]
    then
        echo "home";
    elif [[ "${PWD}" == *scratch* ]]
    then
        echo "scratch";
    elif [[ "${PWD}" == *project* ]]
    then
        echo "project";
    fi

}
```

Then, I export PS1 as:

```
export PS1='$(top_level_dir) : '
```

Unfortunately this is not working as I want. I get `home :` for my prompt when I am in my home directory, but if I switch to scratch or projects then the prompt does not change. I do not understand bash scripting very well so I would appreciate any help to correct my code.

Comment: after you switch to scratch/project, did you execute that `export PS1=...` line again?

Comment: Works for me. What version of bash do you run?

Comment: @choroba It worked for me too on bash 4.2.42. It does not work on 4.1.2. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can hook into `cd` to change the prompt every time you are changing the working directory. I've asked myself often how to hook into `cd` but I think that I now found a solution. What about adding this to your `~/.bashrc`?:

```
#
# Wrapper function that is called if cd is invoked
# by the current shell
#
function cd {
    # call builtin cd. change to the new directory
    builtin cd $@
    # call a hook function that can use the new working directory
    # to decide what to do
    color_prompt
}

#
# Changes the color of the prompt depending
# on the current working directory
#
function color_prompt {
    pwd=$(pwd)
    if [[ "$pwd/" =~ ^/home/ ]] ; then
        PS1='\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h:\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
    elif [[ "$pwd/" =~ ^/etc/ ]] ; then
        PS1='\[\033[01;34m\]\u@\h:\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
    elif [[ "$pwd/" =~ ^/tmp/ ]] ; then
        PS1='\[\033[01;33m\]\u@\h:\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
    else
        PS1='\u@\h:\w\\$ '
    fi
    export PS1
}


# checking directory and setting prompt on shell startup
color_prompt
```

Comment: I was able to fix the problem with my code, see my comment to konsolebox's answer. I like however your solution to using a hook to change color, I'll use it!

Comment: @deepak Ok. I've changed my answer a little bit. Will look into your solution. But however, your question was nice. Ever thought it is impossible. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Please try this method instead and tell us how it works e.g. how your prompt changes in your home directory, your project or scratch directory, and other directories besides those. Tell us what error messages you see as well. The problem lies within it.

Tell me also how you run it, if it's by script, by direct execution, or through a startup script like ~/.bashrc.

```
top_level_dir ()
{
    __DIR=$PWD
    case "$__DIR" in
    *home*)
        echo home
        ;;
    *scratch*)
        echo scratch
        ;;
    *project*)
        echo project
        ;;
    *)
        echo "$__DIR"
        ;;
    esac
}

export PS1='$(top_level_dir) : '
export -f top_level_dir
```

If it doesn't work, try changing `__DIR=$PWD` to `__DIR=$(pwd)` and tell us if it helps too. I also would like to confirm if you're really running `bash`. Note that there are many variants of `sh` like `bash`, `zsh`, `ksh`, and `dash` and the one installed and used by default depends on every system. To confirm that you're using Bash, do `echo "$BASH_VERSION"` and see if it shows a message.

You should also make sure that you're running `export PS1='$(top_level_dir) : '` with single quotes and not with double quotes: `export PS1="$(top_level_dir) : "`.

Comment: You were right about checking for single quotes instead. Thanks! I was actually using double quotes. My code worked after changing to single quotes. It works now for both version 4.2 and 4.1.