# How can I change the color of my bash PS1 based on the current working directory?

Tags: bash, colors

Title says it all. For example, I might want my PS1 to be green when I'm inside `/my-app-1/`:

[image: Bash shell with green text]

...but blue if I'm inside `/my-app-2/`:

[image: Bash shell with blue text]

Comment: What if you're in `/` or `~` or any other directory?

Comment: @Cyrus - In that case I'd probably want the PS1 to be white or light gray.

Comment: Does [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18243946/shell-prompt-that-is-based-on-location-in-filesystem) cover your question?

Comment: @BenjaminW. - Yes, that does!  Thanks!