# How to configure .condarc so it creates new environments in current directory by default

Tags: python, configuration, anaconda

I want conda create to create a new environment in my current directory by default.

I understand that I can do this with the `--prefix` [command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37926940/how-to-specify-new-environment-location-for-conda-create), but I want this to be the default behavior.  Can I specify the conda prefix to `./` in .condarc?

Any other suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the [CONDA_ENVS_PATH](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html#specify-environment-directories-envs-dirs) environment variable and set/remove the working directory to this every time you change directory.

You can [wrap cd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18243946/shell-prompt-that-is-based-on-location-in-filesystem) to do this. On Windows I would do the equivalent using powershell.

Alternatively you can simply alias the conda create command with the additional `--prefix` argument.